# Update only changed fields in JOOQ record using POJO

Tags: java, database, orm, jooq

I'd like to update the changed fields in a JOOQ record using a POJO as the source. [`Record.from(Object)`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/3.8.x/org/jooq/Record.html#from-java.lang.Object-) is nearly right, but according to the docs

> The resulting record will have its internal "changed" flags set to true for all values.

I would like only the fields which have actually changed (as determined by say, [`Objects.equals(Object, Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#equals(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object))) to have their flags updated.

The two reasons for this are:

- I don't want to trigger an insert
- I only want to send new values to the database in the update statement (bandwidth, concurrent updates, etc)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for this implementation ...

> The resulting record will have its internal "changed" flags set to true for all values.

... is simple: If things weren't implemented this way, there would be no way to enforce an update of a value that hasn't changed. There are some use-cases where this is desireable (e.g. batching, avoiding too many different SQL strings, etc.). The [`Record.from()`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Record.html#from-java.lang.Object-) method is just consistent with the other `Record` methods, e.g. [`Record.set(Field, Object)`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Record.html#set-org.jooq.Field-T-).

You can patch the internal changed flags as such:

```
// Load all values and mark them all as "changed"
record.from(object);

// Undo the undesired flags
for (int i = 0; i < record.size(); i++)
    if (Objects.equals(record.get(i), record.original(i)))
        record.changed(i, false);
```

I've also created a feature request in jOOQ. Perhaps the API could be improved as a lot of people have this requirement:
https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/5394

Comment: Adding a feature would be great. `Record.original()` is also perfect for enabling users to implement it ourselves in the meantime, thanks.

Comment: The only way to know which fields need to be marked as changed is by either loading the record from the database prior to update, or keeping a change state in the pojo. In such a case, I'd rather directly work with the record object.

Comment: @Lukas, I have similar workflow where I get a POJO where I need to update only non null and changed fields. The way I am trying to is by starting with retrieving the object from the database. After the null check and above changed check, I want to make sure I set only the modified fields to the record object. Somewhere doing something wrong and seeing the following error:
Field ('"db"."table"."description"') is not contained in Row (). This is my code.

existingRecord.setValue(DSL.val(existingRecord.field(i)), DSL.val(newRecord.getValue(i)));

Comment: @chetu: I see you've already asked a question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/70341411/521799

Comment: Thank you for your help. I really appreciate your effort to continuing to improve JOOQ library and staying on top of any JOOQ related questions.