# Update only changed fields in JOOQ record using POJO with partial data

Tags: java, jooq

I have a very similar issue as the following post, but slight variation.
[Update only changed fields in JOOQ record using POJO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38003752/update-only-changed-fields-in-jooq-record-using-pojo/38199329#38199329)

I get the same JSON object both for create and update call. In the update call, I might not receive all the fields, so I want to make sure I update only the changed fields and not replace the fields that weren't provided with null. There is no constraint on the database.

I am following the above answer, but running into an error with slight modification.

```java
UserRecord existingRecord = existingUserRecordOptional.get();
UserRecord newUserRecord = new UserRecord();
newUserRecord.from(userPojo);

for (int i = 0; i < newRecord.size(); i++) {
   if (nonNull(newRecord.get(i)) && !Objects.equals(existingConsumerRecord.get(i), newRecord.get(i))) {
      existingUserRecord.setValue(DSL.val(existingUserRecord.field(i)), DSL.val(newUserRecord.getValue(i)));
   }
}
```

Error I am receiving is:

*Field ('"db"."table"."description"') is not contained in Row (...)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this instead:

```java
existingUserRecord.setValue(
  // Don't wrap this in DSL.val()
  (Field) existingUserRecord.field(i), 
  DSL.val(newUserRecord.getValue(i))
);
```

[`DSL.val()`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/bind-values/) is used to create a bind value.

However, since you've linked to [the previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38003752/update-only-changed-fields-in-jooq-record-using-pojo/38199329#38199329), why not just follow that approach that doesn't copy values between records? You could use the `newUserRecord` and unset all changed flags for the columns you don't want to send to the database.

Comment: Even with previous approach, it is still overriding existing values with null hence exploring this route where load the record from the DB and only set the changed values to the record object. 

I am still debugging why the other approach is not working. New to JOOQ and the codebase so taking a bit longer.

Comment: This flow resolved the issue for me. With the approach in the previous question, it didn't work for me because some of the way POJO was setup and naming mismatch with DB fields. I will take up refactoring task to streamline this issue. I am planning to explore JPA annotation route to see if code can be better refactored.